# print specific line and then some more

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to search a file for a pattern and if the it is found I want to see the line and 10 more lines of the result.

so far I have

```
grep -n pattern file | cut -d: f1
```

now not sure how to use this out put to do the print with the logic like

```
sed -n result,(result+10)p file
```

probably  going to have a few issued if it pattern is in multiple lines.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `grep -A` is not working, try

`awk '/pattern/ {for(i=0;i<number_of_lines;i++){print;getline}}' <filename>`

else sed has another dirty solution

`sed -n '/pattern/ {p;n;p;n;p;...}' <filename>` here p-> print, n -> get to next line. So number of p is your number of lines to be printed

Update:

to use as a function, write in a test.sh

```
jobcheck(){
  awk "/$1/"' {for(i=0;i<10;i++){print;getline}}' $2
}
```

then just

```
source test.sh
```

to run,

```
jobcheck "pattern" "file"
```

Update:
as per Jonathan Leffler's suggestion, if any of the next 10 lines contains the pattern, counting should start from that line so

```
pattern  ->start printing from here to next 10 lines
blah
blah
pattern  ->forget about the last 2 lines, start counting from here
blah 
blah
```

So updated awk command will be like

```
awk '/pattern/{max_line=NR+2} {if(NR<=max_line) print}' <filename>
```

Similarly inside jobcheck will also be changed. Cheers:)

Comment: Awesome how can I make this a function like : jobcheck(){awk '/$1/ {for(i=0;i<10;i++){print;getline}}' $2 }

Comment: I updated the answer for that :)

Comment: Note that if the patterns appears in the next 10 lines, you should (probably) reset the 'print counter'.  Or design it so that when you find the match, you set `max_print = NR + 10;` and then for each line, `if (NR < max_print) print`

Comment: yes, that's a good suggestion, updated the answer :)

Comment: hmm I put this function to my ~/.bashrc since it is short but I got an error saying syntax error: unexpected end of file. 
I didn't even put the function at the end of the file though. You know what might be the issue?

Comment: I tried jobcheck(){awk "/$1/"' {for(i=0;i<10;i++){print;getline}}' $2}
and jobcheck(){ awk $1 ' {for(i=0;i<10;i++){print;getline}}' $2} both gave the same error

Comment: I think you are putting the function all in same line. try maintaining the newlines as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Using grep 2.10:

```
grep -A 10 "pattern" your_file
```

will print 10 lines after the match

From the [grep man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Context-Line-Control):

> -A num
>
> --after-context=num
>
> Print num lines of trailing context after matching lines.

Using GNU awk 3.1.8:

```
awk '{if(a-->0) {print; next}} /pattern/{print; a=10}' your_file
```

Comment: it says illegal option for me. I am on bash 3.0.19 I believe

Comment: Your grep version is the important info. grep -V

Comment: yea even that is an illegal option. I assume my stuff is really outdated?

Comment: @yatici updated with an `awk` approach

Comment: You might be using some stripped down version of grep.  If you're on an RPM-based distribution you can probably do `rpm -ql grep` or on a DEB-based distribution, `dpkg -l grep` to get the version.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
sed -n '/pattern/{N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;N;p;}'
```

or

```
sed '1,/pattern/{/pattern/!d;}' | sed '12,$d'
```